# AudioKit export file with Filters

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

i want to override an existing .m4a file with many filters with audio kit, my code :

```
file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: recordVoiceURL)
        player =  AKPlayer(audioFile: file)

        delay = AKVariableDelay(player)
        delay.rampTime = 0.5
        delayMixer = AKDryWetMixer(player, delay)

        reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delayMixer)
        reverbMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delayMixer, reverb)
        booster = AKBooster(reverbMixer)
        tracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(booster)
        AudioKit.output = tracker
        try AudioKit.start()
```

i am changing the values of my filters and it works perfectly , now i need to export a new file which include my original file + the EQ filters applied but i don't know how with AudioKit or with AVFoundation

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Try AudioKit's renderToFile once you have your filters setup:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/79cebe3ff8acc64e743b9e9536693c193e478eb4/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AVAudioEngine%2BExtensions.swift#L24

Comment: render to file work only if you play all the song along with filters but i just need a function like renderToFile offline but without playing all the file , i need just to apply the filters on an AKAudioFile and export him with one function.

Comment: to more understand me , i am doing a karaoke app and i have a studio controller where i can change between filters like Sing by Smule. i am doing the exact app like Sing by Smule

Comment: Aure , nevermind , i have understand the offline render, sorry to bother you and it worked thank you.

Comment: @atacand1920 can you share your solution? I'm running in a similar situation, where I need to render the whole audio file going through a TimePitch filter. How did you achieve that? I tried renderToFile, but the file ends up being empty (although the duration metadata is fine)

Comment: Any news on that?