# exporting filtered audio using AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I've been unable to find any examples that walk one through how to export audio that you have piped through AudioKit's filters.

I have found an [example of how to simply export audio](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Playback/Exporting%20Files/) using the `exportAsynchronously` method on an `AKAudioFile` object, but (and I would think this would be a very common use case for AudioKit) what about audio you've actually manipulated with AudioKit's filters or other effects?

[In this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633999/3772347), there is a reference to using the `renderToFile()` method, but I've tried this and when I play back the audio, it's just the original source audio and not the filtered audio.

So far, I am setting up the AudioKit file and player w/filters thusly:

```
            AKPlayer = try AKAudioPlayer(file: fileFromTranscodedVideoOutputPath)

            // track frequencies from player
            tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(AKPlayer)

            AKPlayer.connect(to: mixer.inputNode)

            // piping through to tracker for analysis data from player
            AudioKit.output = tracker


            // SETUP EQs
            filterBand1 = AKEqualizerFilter(AKPlayer, centerFrequency: 64, bandwidth: 70.8, gain: 1.0)
            filterBand2 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand1, centerFrequency: 125, bandwidth: 141, gain: 1.0)

            let outputMixer = AKMixer(filterBand8)
            AudioKit.output = outputMixer
            AudioKit.start()

            /* then I present the player w/EQ sliders and everything works as-is, but when I try to render or export the audio that has been filtered in the following way, and then play it back, I only ever end up with the original source audio sound that is unaltered */

            // this func initializes an AVAudio file
            let audioFile = createAVAudioFile()

            // now trying to render to file
            try AudioKit.renderToFile(audioFile, duration: 10.0, prerender: {self.AKPlayer.play()})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, I think this should work as you've laid it out. Any chance you could put an example project up on Github?

Comment: I mean, there are some question marks in your code like multiple places the AudioKit.output is set, but a project would be the quickest to debug.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Thanks a lot for taking a look! I will clean up the project I have with this and share  a link to the git repo, much appreciated.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Hi Aurelius, sent you a link to a basic project, thought I'd ping you here too: how do we know when renderToFile() has finished? Is it blocking? (Doesn't seem to be or maybe it's not working properly)